# How to solve sqlite_error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I used an android studio and got a below message. but I'm don't Know.....  what should I do?

```
***E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.mygallery, PID: 1315 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mygallery/com.example.mygallery.MainActivity}:** android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: datetakenDESC (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): ,
```

Answer (score 1):

the Column name is incorrect check the check that the letters are uppercase and lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a space here `datetakenDESC`, so Sqlite engine thinks this as a column name.
This should be `datetaken DESC`